# How can I use .xcconfig files in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcconfig

I just switched over to Xcode 4 and I'm having trouble working with .xcconfig files for build settings. My targets that already had files assigned in Xcode 3 are all set up - a column titled Config.file shows up in the Levels view of Build Settings. But I can't figure out how to edit the columns in this view or where to put an .xcconfig file to attach it to a new target. I've looked online and haven't found an answer. Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Pick File | New, choose Other and "Configuration Settings File", this gets you a new .xcconfig file.

Then click on the project on the upper left in the file browser (the same place where you get to build settings), click on the project again in the second-to-left panel, and click on the Info tab at the top of the inner panel.

There, you can choose "Based on Configuration File" for each of your targets for each of your configurations (debug, release, etc.)

Comment: Just in case Xcode doesn't do it for you, the .xcconfig file needs to be added to the project before it can be used as a Configuration File.

Comment: Can I put add variables like "API_URL" in the configuration file? In that case, how do I access them using swift?

Comment: i have two variables in .xcconfig. how do i get value for different tragets?

Comment: Upvoted. Worth mentioning here as well that we can change the xcconfig for Unit or UI Test Bundle targets too within the same project.

Answer (score 59):

Great answer from Mike Kale. If the description was not clear enough, here is a screenshot.

[image: xcconfig in the project configuration]

Comment: one thing i don't understand is this: when you copy over a config file to the project.. you get prompted to click on each project that you wish the config file to apply to.. but then in the above screenshot.. there is a dropdown beside the project file *and* a dropdown beside *each* target.. so if I selected all targets in the first step.. so i still have to assign it to each target drop down menu?

Comment: the answer is the latter (ie you still have to assign the config file for *each* target..)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the great answer already added by @MikeKale.

### Build settings

If you have successfully added a new `xcconfig` file and mapped it to a target in the project settings, your build settings will be automatically updated.

Note that if you are depending on scheme pre-action or post-action shell scripts, or just updating the build settings in the Xcode environment, no extra work is needed to read the new variable as per the `$(VARIABLE_NAME)` convention.

### Update in Xcode 14.3 for UI Tests and other target types

The Project settings page looks different in Xcode 14.3, and I've attached a screenshot below showing how we can even add a custom `.xcconfig` to UI Test or Unit Test targets too. Note that we call a `xcconfig` a separate *build* configuration.

[image: Add build xcconfig to UI Tests scheme]

### Reading `.xcconfig` values from Swift

The below steps are for reading `.xcconfig` environment variables from a Swift environment.

#### Example `.xcconfig`

```
CI_RUN = true
```

#### Environment variables

```
class Environment {
    static func variable(name: String) -> String? {
        ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment[name]
    }
}
```

#### Example usage

```
print(Environment.variable(name: "CI_RUN") ?? "false")
// prints true
```