# LLVM compiler settings, clarification needed

Tags: xcode

Are compiler settings set per project or once and for all?

For example, can one declare:

> For all projects i create from this day forth, until told otherwise,
>   treat all warnings as errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Xcode*, just use shared/global xcconfig files. Definitions at the project and target levels have precedence if defined, so you can make exceptions and/or combine them in many ways.

**Xcconfig Crash Course:**

[This Q+A will explain the configuration.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208224/how-can-i-use-xcconfig-files-in-xcode-4)

Then you just fill the xcconfig file with the build settings you want, like so:

```
ADDITIONAL_SDKS = 
ARCHS = x86_64
SDKROOT = macosx10.7
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = NO
SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS = macosx
VALID_ARCHS = i386 ppc ppc64 ppc7400 ppc970 x86_64
```

Other notes:

- You can `#include` xcconfig files in xcconfig files (with some restrictions)
- You can drag+drop build settings from Xcode's build settings view to a text file.

So, if all you want is "Treat warnings as errors", your xcconfig would have this:

```
GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS = YES
```

Comment: Updated tags to include IDE. Can you please tell me more about `shared/ global xconfig files`? Where are they? How should they be edited?