# Is there any way to override build settings per person in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I'm working on an iPhone app which connects to several services via REST API.

There are some servers for each service(development, production, etc),
and I want to switch these servers to connect by compiler flags WITHOUT modifying foo.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj.

I'm in a team of 6 developers and each person wants to connect to different servers combination,
but it will be a mess if I include these configuration in project.pbxproj which is managed by git.

So I need to change compiler flags with a file which is not managed by git.

Ideally, I want local settings mechanism like in Django.
Is there any ways to do this with Xcode?

Thanks! Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you set up 6 different targets with their own build settings that use the same files in the project.  It could get tricky, but everyone that adds files could make sure to add them to all the targets and it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!
But I don't want to do this, because we already have 3 targets (iPhone, iPad, and one more).
It will be a mess 18 targets in 1 project file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having your compiler flags not under source control is a huge RED FLAG. How can you guarantee consistent building of your app. // End Soap Box

**Answer**

I would create a user defined build setting for the production and dev servers. And a run script to set the server to use in the application info.plist

- Add build setting REST_Server

[image]
[image]

- Add run script to update the info.plist

[image]
[image]

```
# ---------------------------- IMPORTANT ----------------------------
# You must set RESTServer to something like 'Set by build script' in the file
# file '<Project Name>-Info.plist' in the 'Supporting Files' group
# -------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# determin server based on user name
#

SERVER=${REST_Server}

# Only use developer servers for debug never for release
if [ "$CONFIGURATION" != "Debug" ] ; then
    exit
fi

if [ "$USER" == "gdunham" ] ; then
    SERVER="gld.nextbigthing.com"
fi

if [ "$USER" == "jashmun" ] ; then
    SERVER="jda.nextbigthing.com"
fi

echo $SERVER

#
# Set the server info in plist file in the build product not the source tree
#
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :RESTServer $SERVER" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}"
```

- Add place holder to  info.plist

[image]

For all the gory details see my demo project on GitHub
https://github.com/GayleDDS/DemoMultiDeveloper

Comment: "Having your compiler flags not under source control is a huge RED FLAG. How can you guarantee consistent building of your app."
I don't think it's so dangerous. I want to overwrite just couple of parameters of settings. Base settings should be managed, of course.
making local_settings.py for overwriting params is ordinary way in web app development with Django.

Anyway, your suggestion is awesome! This is almost exactly I wanted to do!
I didn't know PlistBuddy. Cool!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the build configuration (.xcconfig)files to create different combinations of servers. Here is good explanation for how to configure this for your project: [How can I use .xcconfig files in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208224/how-can-i-use-xcconfig-files-in-xcode-4)

Each user can have their own .xcconfig file(s) and you can add these .xcconfig files to .gitignore

Comment: Thank you for your information! It's close.

But it seems that local.xcconfig must be included in the xcodeproj to specify the file as base config.

This means local.xcconfig should be managed on git, I think.
Is this correct? How can I handle this problem?

Comment: You are right that local.xcconfig file is included in the xcodeproj but it doesn't need to be in git. XCode will be able to build even if this file is not there on the workspace (of-course only if it has all the settings that it needs in project build settings within Xcode)

Comment: Umm, if I don't add local.xcconfig to git and specify it as base config, other members can't build because they don't have local.xcconfig. Xcode will complaints "local.xcconfig: No such file or directory". What should I do for this?

Comment: My understanding is that XCode will overwrite the project settings from .xcconfig file. It will use the settings defined in XCode for those missing in this file. If the file isn't there then it will try to build with just XCode settings.

Comment: Ah yes, Xcode does overwrite the settings. But it won't skip .xcconfig file.

So it fails if .xcconfig file doesn't exist in xcodeproj. I tested with Xcode 4.6.3. Which Xcode are you using?

Comment: I just tried in XCode 4.6.2, and getting the same error. Can you add a empty file in git and developer's can overwrite?

Comment: Yes, it will work. 
But all members must keep the modified unstage local.xcconfig...
Umm...