# Xcode: Change Build settings globally?

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I wanted to make a changed to Documentation comments which can be found under build settings and Apple llvm 5.1 warnings -all languages.

I have changed it and its working on my project, but is it possible to make this change globally so that every new project I create has this setting?

I would like the compiler by default to check my documentation comments for errors and do not want to set this setting manually each time I create a project

Answer (score 0):

Use a configuration settings file. What you need to do is add a configuration settings file to your project, place the build setting you want to change in the configuration settings file, and tell your project to use the configuration settings file. The following question provides more detailed instructions on setting up a configuration settings file in Xcode:

[How can I use .xcconfig files in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208224/how-can-i-use-xcconfig-files-in-xcode-4)

The question covers Xcode 4, but adding configuration settings files didn't change from Xcode 4 to Xcode 5.