# To change bundle identifier using command line (xcodebuild)

Tags: ios, xcode5, xcodebuild

I have two bundle identifiers which i need to specify in terminal while generating ipa file.
Can anyone suggest me ?

To generate ipa file i have used below command

> xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat ipa -archivePath
>   "/Users/xxx/Downloads/Example-MKLocalSearch-master/LocalSearchExample.xcarchive"
>   -exportPath "/Users/xxx/Desktop/LocalSearch.ipa" -exportProvisioningProfile "xxx Development"

here i want to specify bundle identifier.
Any suggestions?

Is it possible?

Comment: Is it possible? Any idea?

Comment: Somebody knows how to solve it?

Comment: got it by using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208224/how-can-i-use-xcconfig-files-in-xcode-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it by following link [How can I use .xcconfig files in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208224/how-can-i-use-xcconfig-files-in-xcode-4)

mentioned bundle identifier in config files

and from terminal: xcodebuild -xcconfig filename